# Update using select query with multiple Rows in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle9i

Can any one please help me to solve this issue

Table Name:RW_LN

```
  LN_ID      RE_LN_ID     RE_PR_ID   
  LN001        RN001       RN002
  LN002        RN002       RN003
  LN003        RN003       RN001  
  LN004        RN001       RN002
```

MY Update Query is:

```
update table RW_LN set RE_LN_ID=(
    select LN_ID
    from RW_LN as n1,RW_LN as n2
    where n1.RE_LN_ID = n2.RE_PR_ID)
```

MY Expected Result is:

```
     LN_ID           RE_LN_ID  
     LN001            LN003  
     LN002            LN004  
     LN003            LN002  
     LN004            LN003
```

This above query shows error as `SUB QUERY RETURNS MULTIPLE ROWS`.Can any one provide the solution for this, I am Beginner in Oracle 9i.So Stuck in the logic

Comment: please show what result you want after your update, cause your query doesn't help much.

Comment: hI pLEASE REFER MY EXPECTED RESULT FORMAT,THANKS

Comment: so the problem is : LN002 has RE_LN_ID : RN002, which can be related to RE_PR_ID from LN001 or LN004. Why do you choose LN004 (this is usefull to build the query)

Comment: @Sajini: The edits you made to your question made it completely meaningless. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to solve this with a `distinct`

```
update table RW_LN set RE_LN_ID=(  
      select distinct LN_ID   
      from RW_LN as n1,RW_LN as n2  
      where     n1.RE_LN_ID = n2.RE_PR_ID)
```

if that still returns multiple rows, it means you are missing a join somewhere along the way or potentially have a bad schema that needs to use primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but possibly this is what you want.

```
update
  RW_LN n1
set
  RE_LN_ID=(  
    select n2.LN_ID   
    from   RW_LN n2  
    where  n1.RE_LN_ID = n2.RE_PR_ID)
where exists (
    select null   
    from   RW_LN n2  
    where  n1.RE_LN_ID = n2.RE_PR_ID and
           n2.ln_id is not null)
```

At the moment there is no correlation between the rows you are updating and the value being returned in the subquery.

The query reads as follows:

```
For every row in RW_LN change the value of RE_LN_ID to be:
  the value of LN_ID in a row in RW_LN for which:
    the RE_PR_ID equals the original tables value of RE_LN_ID
IF there exists at least one row in RW_LN for which:
    RE_PR_ID is the same as RE_LN_ID in the original table AND
    LN_ID is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take the "biggest" corresponding LN_ID, you could do

```
update RW_LN r1
set r1.RE_LN_ID = (select MAX(LN_ID)
                FROM RW_LN r2
                where r1.RE_LN_ID = r2.RE_PR_ID);
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7cd19/1)

But you should explain why you choose (as new RE_LN_ID) LN004 instead of LN001 for LN_ID LN002 (cause you could choose both)